# Multiplying Aliases in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an assignment where I must create an invoice uing SQL, I have ran into a problem when attempting innerjoins for the first time and am extremely new to all this. When trying to multiply a created alias it throws up an error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'Bookings.CostumeID' in 'field list'

I have no idea what Im doing wrong and the first two alias work fine so far.
Any help appreciated!

Code is below

```
SELECT booking.BookingID, booking.CustID, Bookings.CostumeID, booking.DateIn,
booking.DateOut, booking.DateDue, customer.Fname, customer.Sname, costume.Description,

DateIn-DateOut AS TotalDays,
DateIn-DateDue AS LateDays,
LateDays*10 AS Penalty

FROM booking
INNER JOIN customer ON booking.CustID = customer.CustID
INNER JOIN costume ON booking.CostID = costume.CostID
where BookingID=1
```

Comment: Your table is `booking` not `bookings`, so replace `Bookings.CostumeID` with `Booking.CostumeID`.

Comment: Thats Slavoo for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are worngly using `Bookings.CostumeID`.

Use `booking.CostumeID` instead of `Bookings.CostumeID`

Try this query

```
SELECT booking.BookingID, booking.CustID, booking.CostumeID, booking.DateIn,
booking.DateOut, booking.DateDue, customer.Fname, customer.Sname, costume.Description,

DateIn-DateOut AS TotalDays,
DateIn-DateDue AS LateDays,
(DateIn-DateDue)*10 AS Penalty

FROM booking
INNER JOIN customer ON booking.CustID = customer.CustID
INNER JOIN costume ON booking.CostID = costume.CostID
where BookingID=1
```